# How to implement CustomView that contains other views (such as a Button, TextView, CheckBox, etc) without adding up to the view hierarchy in android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a view that contains `TextView` (on the left) and `Button` (on the right) and a `SeekBar` at the Bottom, something like this.

```
|-----------------------------------|
| <TextView>               <Button> |
|  <           SeekBar           >  |
|-----------------------------------|
```

Note that angle brackets represents the width, just used for demonstration.

I can do that by creating a `CompoundView` but I wanted to keep things flat.

I'm going to create others similar to this one and there will be a lot of these.

Please ask for any further clarifications (if needed).

Thank you.

Comment: I know that I can create my own custom views but that will be a lot since I have to write the code from the scratch for rendering my view and implementing the behaviours that are already there.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a `Framelayout` and adding your views on the go?

```
public class Cell extends FrameLayout {

private TextView tv;
private Button btn;
private ProgressBar progressBar;



public Cell (Context context, int width, int height) {
    super(context);
    getLayoutParams().width = width;
    getLayoutParams().height = height;
    
    tv = new TextView(context);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams tvParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT);
    tv.setLayoutParams(tvParams);

    btn = new Button(context);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams btnParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.TOP|Gravity.RIGHT);
    btn.setLayoutParams(btnParams);

    progressBar = new ProgressBar(context);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams progressParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.BOTTOM);
    progressBar.setLayoutParams(progressParams);


    addView(tv);
    addView(btn);
    addView(progressBar);
}

public void setText (String text) {
    tv.setText(text);
}

public void setProgress (int progress) {
    progressBar.setProgress(progress);
}
}
```

Note that you might need to use other constructors as well.

Comment: Well this will not flatten the view hierarchy.